# Solve the following Bernoulli ODE

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

Solve the following Bernoulli ODE: $\frac{dy}{dx}+x·y=xy^{-1}$

I have managed to find the integrating factor which is $2xdx$. Integrating this results in $e^{x^2}$.
I am unsure on how to proceed in obtaining the final answer, which is $y(x)=\sqrt{1+Ce^{-x^2}}$

Comment: Please explain how your integrating factor is integrating. I only see $2y$ as doing something useful.

Comment: [link]https://i.imgur.com/zY4VF4D.jpg  
Im still new to this, I meant that my p(x) is 2x, resulting in the e^integration 2xdx.

Comment: Is it supposed to be $xy^{-1}$ like $\displaystyle \frac{x}{y}$ or $(xy)^{-1}$ like $\displaystyle \frac{1}{xy}$?

Comment: xy^-1 like x/y, sorry for the misunderstanding, edited.

Answer (score 2):

This is the differential you have in the pic:
$$\frac{dy}{dx}+x·y=x·y^{-1}$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx^2}\dfrac {dx^2}{dx}+x·y=xy^{-1}$$
$$2\frac{dy}{dx^2}+y=y^{-1}$$
$$2y\frac{dy}{dx^2}+y^2=1$$
$$\frac{dy^2}{dx^2}+y^2=1$$
$$u'+u=1$$
Where $u=y^2$. This is separable. Integrate.
$$\int \dfrac {du}{u-1}=-\int dx^2$$

Answer (score 2):

Multiplying by $ y $ , it becomes

$$y\frac{dy}{dx}+xy^2=x$$

or, with $ z=y^2$

$$\frac 12 z' +xz =x$$
Observe that $ z=\color{red}{1}$ is a particular solution.

thus

$$z=C.e^{-x^2}+\color{red}{1}=y^2$$